# Meromorphic function bounded in a (sufficiently) large sector is actually entire

Tags: complex-analysis

During my research I came across the following question which I could resolve in a special case but now I also would be interested in a general answer.

Let $0 < \delta < \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\alpha \geq 1$. Denote by $S_{\frac{\pi}{2} - \delta}$ the open sector symmetric around the positive real axis with opening angle $\frac{\pi}{2} - \delta$ and $f: \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{C}$ holomorphic and such that $f$ is bounded on $\left(S_{\frac{\pi}{2} - \delta}\right)^c$ (complement in the complex plane) and 
\begin{equation}
 \exists C > 0 \, \forall z \in \mathbb{C}, \, \Re z > 0: \, |f(z)| \leq \frac{C}{(\Re z)^{\alpha}}. 
\end{equation}
Does this imply that $f$ is actually entire, i.e.\ it has a continuation in $z=0$ such that the resulting function is holomorphic? Ideas for a possible proof or a counter example would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will sketch the proof: using that in the given sector, the absolute value of $z$ is bounded by the real part of $z$ times a constant ($sin(\delta)$^(-1)),  transform the inequality there with absolute value instead of real part, so there is a positive integer $m$ s.t. $z^mf$ is bounded on the sector intersected say with the unit disc. This implies $z^mf$ bounded on the unit disc minus the origin, hence you remove the singularity, so $f$ can be at worst meromorphic at zero. But boundness on the exterior of the sector precludes poles (as $f$ would go to infinity at 0) so $f$ is entire.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are of course perfectly right. I think we can even generalise and say a bit more. Say we have a bound like $|f(z)| \leq C |z|^{-\alpha}$. Then $z^m f$ is holomorphic. If there is a sequence $(z_n)$ such that $z_n \to 0$ and $|f(z_n)|$  is bounded (in the above example choose one in the exterior of the discussed sector) it follows that $z^{m-1}f$ is even holomorphic and one can repeat the argument until we find $f$ to be holomorphic and by the bound $f=0$. Would you agree?

Comment: yes definitely - any $f$ as above is actually zero once you show it's entire